# Angular creating another instance of same component instead of updating the existing one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-material-6

I have a cart component which gets the data from firebase and renders that data on the front-end data. I have some buttons on that component which changes the quantity in firebase( Remove one, Add One ). Whenever the user clicks on that button the quantity is getting changed but angular, instead of updating the existing the component, is creating a new same component with updated quantity and the previous one stays there. ( as shown in the image ). I am not sure what is going wrong as these two buttons are working fine on Product component ( another component for changing the quantity ).
 I have 3 components in my cart, on clicking remove one, they are getting rendered again.

My Code:-

cartComponent.ts

```
export class CartComponent{

cart$ = [];
totalPrice$: number = 0;

constructor( private cart: CartService) {
    this.getCartData().then( data => data );
}

async getCartData() {

    if( this.cart$.length > 0 ){
        for( let i=0; i<this.cart$.length; i++ ){
            let item  = this.cart$[i];
            console.log( item );
            for(let key in this.cart$[i]){
                console.log( item[key]["product"]["quantity"] );
                if( item[key]["product"]["quantity"] === 0 ){
                    this.cart$.splice( i, 1 );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let cartId = await this.cart.getOrCreateCartId();
    let cart = await firebase.database().ref(  '/cart/' + cartId + '/items/');
    cart.on( 'value', (snapshot) => {
        let items = snapshot.val();
        for( let key in items ){
            this.cart$.push( items[key ]);
            this.totalPrice$ += parseFloat( items[key]["product"]["price"] ) *  parseFloat( items[key]["product"]["quantity"] );
        }
    });
}

removeFromCart( product ){
    this.cart.removeFromCart( product );
}

addToCart( product ){
    this.cart.addToCart( product );
}
}
```

cartComponent.html

```
<div id="center">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="cart$.length === 0; content"></mat-spinner>
</div>
<mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let item of cart$">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem">
        <p class="title-width">{{ item.product.title }}</p>
        <p class="left-margin">Price:</p>&nbsp;<p matBadge="{{ item.product.quantity * item.product.price }}" matBadgeOverlap="false"></p>
        <p class="left-margin">Quantity:</p>&nbsp;<p matBadge="{{ item.product.quantity }}" matBadgeColor="accent" matBadgeOverlap="false"></p>
        <p class="left-margin"><button mat-raised-button style="margin-left: 5px;" (click)="removeFromCart( item.product )" color="warn">Remove one</button></p>
        <p class="left-margin"><button mat-raised-button class="button-padding-left" (click)="addToCart( item.product )" color="primary">Add one</button></p>
        <p class="left-margin"><button mat-raised-button class="button-padding-left" color="warn">Remove all</button></p>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
<div class="container margin">
    <h4>Total Price: {{ totalPrice$ }}</h4>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" color="accent">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

[image: 3 components in my cart, on clicking remove one, they are getting rendered again]

Comment: it looks like the data from cart is coming in asynchronously. have you tried putting "*ngFor="let item of cart$ | async" with the async pipe? Is cart$ an observable?

Comment: @Dream_Cap No, it's not an observable so I don't think I can use async pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by setting the cart array to an empty array again. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do so. But If I am doing this wrong, please let me know in the comments. This is how I fixed the problem.

```
removeFromCart( product ){
        this.cart$ = [];
        this.totalPrice$ = 0;
        this.cart.removeFromCart( product );
    }

    addToCart( product ){
        this.cart$ = [];
        this.totalPrice$ = 0;
        this.cart.addToCart( product );
    }
```

Comment: In your code around `cart.on`, you don't want to keep pushing items into cart object. Ideally, you'd want to find similar item with the same name/id and replace that.